# How to create a getter setter method for a dictionary inside a class in Swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have a class that has a dictionary called users. I want to add and get data from this dictionary from other classes in Swift program. How should I do it?

```
class Database {

    class func addUsers(){
     // i need to know how to create function like such. 
    }

    var userIDName: [String:String] = [
        "A000123" : "AA",
        "A000345" : "BB",
        "A000343" : "CC"
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Database {
    var userIDName = [String: String]()
    func addUser(key: String, value: String) {
        userIDName[key] = value
    }

    func getUsers() -> [String: String] {
        return userIDName
    }
}
```

You can add and get users data like below :

```
var users: [String:String] = [
        "A000123" : "AA",
        "A000345" : "BB",
        "A000343" : "CC"
    ]

let database = Database()

users.forEach({ (key, value) in
    database.addUser(key: key, value: value) // for adding user
})
print(database.getUsers()) // for getting users
```

Comment: `addUsers` should be named `addUser` since it only adds one user.

Comment: I updated the code to be so: 
    func addUser(user: User) {
        users[user.userId] = user
    }
I am using this set method and I getting an error. Any suggestion?  let a = User()  self.addUser(a)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you want it to use as a singleton, like the following:

```
class Database {
    static let shared = Database()

    func addUsers(id: String, name: String) { 
        userIDName[id] = name
    }

    var userIDName = [String: String]()
}

// Usage
let database = Database.shared

database.addUsers(id: "A123", name: "AA")
print(database.userIDName["A123"])
```

Comment: There's no need to make it a singleton. That's not needed and it's not relevant to the question.

Comment: @rmaddy the OP has stated that he would add or retrieve data from other classe**s**, thus I assumed he wants to use it as a single object across the project. Maybe it's not needed, but would you care to elaborate why it is not relevant to the question?